# css trouble combining absolute positioning, max-dimensions and centering

Tags: css, css-position

I've done my share of css, and think I know all the usual tricks, but this one stumped me. I'm trying to absolutely position a caption box over an image (implemented as background-image) with a list of requirements:

- Should be centered
- Should have max-width and max-height as percentages of the image.
- Should have bottom 10% from parent, and resize up with more content
- Text content over maximum size should be hidden, but the background with it's rounded `border-radius` corners should remain visible.

The following is the closest I've come - it fails at centering:

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x400');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 75%;
  max-height: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(75,75,75,0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="caption">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

I know lots of ways to center of course, but none I try maintain the other requirements.

I don't mind wrapping one or more extra elements around `.caption` if it achieves all my aims. Anyone able to help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the caption in another div with the dimensions and positioning you require.

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x400');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.wrap {
  width: 75%;
  max-height: 80%;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  bottom: 10%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  left: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.caption {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(75, 75, 75, 0.4);
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="caption">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
        in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: On my initial try with this, the caption will only expand up to a maximum width of 50% of the parent. I am sure this is related to the `left: 50%`. I can see this is not a problem in the snippet here - do you know if css I have on the container element might cause this behaviour?

Comment: My biggest trouble adapting this is letting the visible box be centered but have variable width - tiny for a one word caption, maxing out at (ex) 75% and wrapping for longer text.

Answer (score 1):

add `left:0px` and `right:0px` to `.caption`

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('http://via.placeholder.com/400x400');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 75%;
  max-height: 25%;
  overflow: hidden;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: rgba(75,75,75,0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="caption">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks promising - giving it a try where I need it. Surprised this works with max-width and margins!

Comment: This did what was desired on Chrome, Firefox, but the caption hugged the left in IE. I *wish* this had worked, because it was a simple add-on, but not too surprised browsers differ in how they resolve `left:0; right: 0; max-width: 75%;`